# Sugeno Fuzzy Output Coefficients

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

if `input 1 = x` and `input 2 = y`, then output `z` is equal to `ax + by + c`.

What do the variables `a`, `b` and `c` correlate to?

Could these be something to do with each rules weight?

How do we calculate `a`, `b` and `c`?

What does that have to do with the data which we have in hand?

Comment: This questions belongs to Cross Validated...

Comment: But... these are handled through the membership function for the Sugeno Fuzzy Model... Are you clear on how a Sugeno Fuzzy Model works?.... When so, ask again or come back

Comment: I know how a Sugeno Fuzzy Works. I have articles about it. But it doesnt state how to find the coefficients in the equation z= ax+by+c

Comment: Ok, so, you are interested in identifying a Sugeno Model based on `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: Off topic, voting to close, agree with @hypco, needs to be reposted on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yeah do you have any idea about it?